# Typescript use type in map

Tags: typescript, types, mapping

I'm trying to create a function to simplify the communication between `Frontend` and `Backend`, but I'm having some issues associating a type to an url.

So, first things first: I'm currently working on a FE/BE which is written in typescript. This made me think:

**The idea:**

"What if I leverage the `RequestType` and make a `generic` function so that I don't have to pass `url: string, requestType, args: T`? Given that we are sharing types between BE and FE, as long as we decide to force 1 type per request, we can write some configuration files containing the request method and request URL (minus the base URL of course) so that every time a request is needed, we can just call something like:

```js
standardRequest<Req, Res>(params: Req, (res: Res) => void)
```

or in alternative:

```js
standardRequest<Req, Res>(params: Req): Res
```

**The issue:**

I'm currently trying to think about ways to map the (typescript) type to the request type (GET, SET, POST, etc...) and the url. Given typescript is not the final language but just the transpile language, if I used `typeof` i would always get `Object`, so I cannot use a `Map` containing `typeof req` as key.

The best solution I can come up with at the moment is a series of `if`s manually casting `instanceof`, but that's not really sustainable, readable nor it scales well.

**An example of what I want to get:**

I would need some help to get to something similar to this (doesn't have to be a map)

```js
Map<type, string>
```

So that I could produce such code:

```js
function connect<T,K>(params: T):K {
// IMPORTANT: the following is not a solution as for custom types I'd get "Object"
const url = typeMap.get(Object.type(params))
axios.get(url, params).then(() => { /*code here */})

//return statement here
}
```

Comment: What's the question? We've got what you're concerned about and what you tried, but we don't really have a question to answer? Are you trying to validate the data at runtime? Or having trouble with the mapping of types to request types?

Comment: @kelly I'm trying to map a type to a value! I'll add an example to make it more clear, sorry for being a bit confusionary!

Comment: Try a runtime type checking solution, like one of [these](https://blog.logrocket.com/methods-for-typescript-runtime-type-checking/).